# 854x480 resolution from mobile Intel 945 chipset

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, resolution

I have an HP nc4400 running Windows 7 64 bit.
The on board graphics is an Intel 945 Express Chipset.

I'd like to connect an Epson TW10 projector via the VGA port. The projector has a native resolution of 854x480.

The nearest 16:9 resolution that I can get is 1280x720.

Is there a way to let me choose 854x480 as the resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the Intel video driver?

http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Laptop+graphics+controllers&ProductProduct=Mobile+Intel%C2%AE+945GM+Express+Chipset+Family&ProdId=2301&LineId=1101&FamilyId=39